# Could not cast value of type (0x10ca9be10) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d8bbb0)

Tags: json, ios, swift, uitableview

Estoy intentando guardar en un arreglo, una serie de datos que seleccionados provenientes de una `tableView` a través de un JSON.

Es decir, la `tableView` muestra unos datos disponibles para seleccionar, los que se vayan seleccionando deseo guardarlos en un arreglo. Pero cuando selecciono un dato en la `tableView` mi app crashea y me muestra un breakpoint:

```
Thread 1: signal SIGABR**T
```

Y en la consola me aparece esto:

```
Could not cast value of type 'MallConcierge.DetallesIntereses' (0x10ca9be10) to 'NSString' (0x7fff86d8bbb0).
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, adjunto las clases de donde descargo los datos, los detalles y la clase donde conecto la `tableView`.

**InteresesModelo.swift** (en esta clase es donde descargo los datos en JSON)

```
import UIKit

protocol InteresesModeloProtocol: class{
    func interesesDownload (interest: NSArray)
}

class InteresesModelo: NSObject {
    
    weak var delegate: InteresesModeloProtocol!
    
    let urlPath = "http://localhost:8888/mallconcierge/API-movil/interests.php"
    
    func interestDownload(){
        
        let url: URL = URL(string: urlPath)!
        let defaultSession = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.ephemeral)
        URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
        let task = defaultSession.dataTask(with: url){
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                
                print("Error al descargar datos")
                
            }else{
                
                print("Datos descargados")
                self.parseJSON(data!)
                
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    
    func parseJSON(_ data:Data){
        
        var jsonResult = NSArray()
        do{
            jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray
        }catch let error as NSError{
            print(error)
        }
        var jsonElement = NSDictionary()
        let detalles = NSMutableArray()
        
        for i in 0 ..< jsonResult.count{
            
            jsonElement = jsonResult[i] as! NSDictionary
            let detalle = DetallesIntereses()
            
            let idInteres = jsonElement["idInteres"]
            let nombreInteres = jsonElement["interesNombre"]
            
            detalle.idInteres = idInteres as? String
            detalle.nombreInteres = nombreInteres as? String
            
            detalles.add(detalle)
            
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { ()-> Void in
            
            self.delegate.interesesDownload(interest: detalles)
        })
            
        
    }

}
```

**DetallesIntereses.swift**

```
import UIKit

class DetallesIntereses: NSObject {
    
    var idInteres: String?
    var nombreInteres: String?
    
    override init() {
        
    }
    
    init(idInteres: String, nombreInteres:String) {
        
        self.idInteres = idInteres
        self.nombreInteres = nombreInteres
        
    }
    
    override var description: String{
        
        return "idInteres: \(idInteres), nombreInteres: \(nombreInteres)"
        
    }

}
```

**InteresesViewController.swift**

```
 import UIKit
    
    class InteresesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource,   InteresesModeloProtocol {
        
        var selectIntereses = [String]()
        
        var feedInterests: NSArray = NSArray()
        
       // var selectInterests: DetallesIntereses = DetallesIntereses()
        
        var items=[String]()
        
        @IBOutlet var listaInteresesTableView: UITableView!
    
        func interesesDownload(interest: NSArray) {
            
            feedInterests = interest
            self.listaInteresesTableView.reloadData()
            
        }
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            
            self.listaInteresesTableView.isEditing = true
            self.listaInteresesTableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
    
            self.listaInteresesTableView.delegate = self
            self.listaInteresesTableView.dataSource = self
            
            let interesesModelo = InteresesModelo()
            interesesModelo.delegate = self
            interesesModelo.interestDownload()
            
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return feedInterests.count
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "celInterests", for: indexPath) as! InteresesTableViewCell
            
            let interest: DetallesIntereses = feedInterests[indexPath.row] as! DetallesIntereses
            
            cell.lblNombreIntereses!.text = interest.nombreInteres
            
            return cell
            
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            
    
            
            self.selectDeselectCell(tableView: listaInteresesTableView, indexPath: indexPath)
            print("Seleccionado")
            
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.selectDeselectCell(tableView: listaInteresesTableView, indexPath: indexPath)
            print("Deseleccionado")
        }
        
        func selectDeselectCell(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath){
            self.selectIntereses.removeAll()
            
            if let arr = listaInteresesTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows{
         
                
                for index in arr{
                    selectIntereses.append(feedInterests[indexPath.row] as! String)
                }
            }
            print(selectIntereses)
        }
        
        @IBAction func seleccionarIntereses(_ sender: Any){
            
            print(selectIntereses)
    
        }
        
        /*
        // MARK: - Navigation
    
        // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
            // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        }
        */
    
    }
```

El JSON

```
[
{
    "idInteres": "1",
    "interesNombre": "Moda Mujer"
},
{
    "idInteres": "3",
    "interesNombre": "Moda Hombre"
},
{
    "idInteres": "4",
    "interesNombre": "Belleza"
},
{
    "idInteres": "5",
    "interesNombre": "Relojes y Joyería"
},
{
    "idInteres": "6",
    "interesNombre": "Hogar/Interiorismo"
},
{
    "idInteres": "7",
    "interesNombre": "Gastronomía"
},
{
    "idInteres": "8",
    "interesNombre": "Entretenimiento"
},
{
    "idInteres": "9",
    "interesNombre": "Wellness"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si imprimes el resultado de `feedInterests[indexPath.row])` vas a ver que es un array porque así lo has declarado:

```
var feedInterests: NSArray = NSArray()
...
idInteres: Optional("9"), nombreInteres: Optional("Wellness")
```

Es por esto que el error es claro y estás convirtiendo ese array en `String` lo que no es permitido.

Si ya tienes el modelo de tus datos en esta clase `DetallesIntereses`, lo más adecuado es que trabajes con este modelo y no con `NSArray`

Te dejo las correcciones de tu código:

1. En el protocolo el parámetro de la función debe ser un array del tipo del modelo:

   ```
   protocol InteresesModeloProtocol: AnyObject{
       func interesesDownload (interest: [DetallesIntereses])
   }
   ```
2. No trabajes con `NSMutableArray()` o `NSArray()` sino con el modelo:

   ```
   //let detalles = NSMutableArray()
   var detalles = [DetallesIntereses]()
   ```
3. En el `for` en donde recorres el json, agregas al nuevo objeto los valores:

   ```
   //detalles.add(detalle)
   detalles.append(detalle)
   ```
4. En el `ViewController` cambias el parámetro de la función del protocolo:

   ```
   //func interesesDownload(interest: NSArray) {
   func interesesDownload(interest: [DetallesIntereses]) {
   ```
5. No uses `NSArray` sino el modelo:

   ```
   //var feedInterests: NSArray = NSArray()
   var feedInterests = [DetallesIntereses]()
   ```
6. En la función para mostrar los datos en la tabla esta conversión ya no tiene sentido:

   ```
   //let interest: DetallesIntereses = feedInterests[indexPath.row] as! DetallesIntereses
   let interest: DetallesIntereses = feedInterests[indexPath.row]
   ```
7. Al seleccionar la celda en esta función `selectDeselectCell` ya no es necesario recorrer el array porque ya puedes acceder a los miembros del modelo de la celda seleccionada:

   ```
   func selectDeselectCell(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath){
    self.selectIntereses.removeAll()

    print(feedInterests[indexPath.row])//idInteres: Optional("6"), nombreInteres: Optional("Hogar/Interiorismo")
    print(feedInterests[indexPath.row].idInteres)//Optional("6")
    print(feedInterests[indexPath.row].nombreInteres)//Optional("Hogar/Interiorismo")
   }
   ```

Comment: Hola Bicho, muchas gracias por la ayuda. 
En la función de 
func selectDeselectCell(tableView: UITableView, indexPath: IndexPath) ...
Lo mejoré un poquito así:
self.selectIntereses.removeAll()
if let arr = listaInteresesTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
for index in arr {
if let interest = feedInterests[index.row] as? DetallesIntereses, let nombre =  interest.nombreInteres {
selectIntereses.append(nombre)
}
}
}
print(selectIntereses)
Y guarda los datos en el arreglo "selectIntereses"
Aprecio y agradezco mucho tu paciencia y tu tiempo por ayudarme. Un abrazo!